# Can ActiveAdmin be used so an Admin User can edit a Mailer Template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My client is wondering if I can set up a page in ActiveAdmin that would allow them to change the message (edit) a registration Mailer view template.

Example of where it would be
[image: example of where it would be]

Is there any way this can be done? I've looked around but am really struggling to find anything remotely similar to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. I will tell you the method to create a better way to handle all such email templates from the Active Admin Dashboard.

1- Create a model named as email_template.rb by running `rails g model email_template`

2- Now add the below code to db/migrate/*timestamp*_create_email_templates.rb

```
def change
  create_table :email_templates do |t|
    t.string    :name
    t.text      :subject
    t.text      :body
  t.timestamps
  end
  add_index :email_templates, [:name], unique: true
end
```

3- Then run `rake db:migrate`

4- Then run `rails generate active_admin:resource EmailTemplate` to add the Email Template to the Active Admin dashboard.

5- Paste the Below code to the admin/email_template.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register EmailTemplate do

  actions :all, except: [:destroy]

  permit_params :name, :subject, :body#, :image

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :name
      f.input :subject
      f.input :body
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

6- Then navigate to the Email Templates from the Active admin Dashboard to create a new Registration Mailer template, assuming named as **welcome_email**

7- Add Subject and Body of the Template from the Active Admin Dashboard.
**Note** - The subject of the Email Template can be added as plain HTML like the below screenshot:

[image]

8- I am assuming that you already have working mail functionality in your application and also have any of the mailers under the ***mailers*** folder like *user_mailer.rb*. If not then please add a mailer first, it'll help you a lot in the future too. You can follow this [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for any help in mailers.

9- Add a function that would be called when the ***welcome_email*** will be called to send any of the User under *mailers/user_mailer.rb* like this:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

before_action { @user = params[:user] }

  def welcome_email
    email   = EmailTemplate.find_by_name("welcome_email")
    mail(:to => @user.email,
            :subject => email.subject, 
            :body => ERB.new(email.body).result_with_hash(user: @user), 
            content_type: "text/html"
            )
  end
end
```

10- Now, you just need to call the above function where do you need the send the mail functionality like in the ***controllers/users/registrations_controller*** (*I am using the modified devised controller*) like this:

```
def create
  super do |user|
    if user.save
      UserMailer.with(user: user).welcome_email.deliver
    end
  end
end
```

As the same above you can add multiple Email Templates and handle all of them from the Active Admin Dashboard and call them wherever you need them by adding a function to the mailer.